# Video tag doesn't load in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-video

I have been struggling to debug why video doesn't load in Safari on my Mac. I set all the necessary headers correctly and even tried to manually call `load()`. I appreciate any help or hint. Thank you.

Server Response

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
x-powered-by: Express
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; media-src 'self' blob:
accept-ranges: bytes
etag: "30bee860901d9f359ac694776f9eebab-1"
last-modified: Wed, 17 Feb 2021 03:04:31 GMT
content-type: video/webm
date: Wed, 17 Feb 2021 03:05:08 GMT
connection: close
Content-Range: bytes 0-139568/139569
Content-Length: 139569
```

Html code:

```
<video playsinline="" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin: auto;"> 
   <source src="/learning/api/recordings/6/contents" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

I even tried this but no success:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].load();
```

[image]

Comment: try removing first `/` from src and include `.webm` or other extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari does not support webm, unless it is a webRTC context.  I'd suggest re-encoding as an mp4 (h264 for all browsers, h265 if you're looking for a Safari codec)

[image: caniuse screenshot of WEbm]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing first `/` from src and include `.webm` or other file extensions.
This might happen because you are accessing from `root`. Instead, use relative path.
Something like `<source src="learning/api/recordings/6/contents.webm" type="video/webm">`

*(Full code with file structure is required to completely answer **if** this doesn't solve your problem)*

Comment: please share file structure